# Minimization of Norm Function

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Let $C$ be a symmetric and idempotent $m\times m$ real matrix. Let $z=\left[z_1 \cdots z_m\right]^T$ such that $z_i\in\{0,1\}$ for each $i=1,\ldots,m$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times 1}$. We wish to find,

$\operatorname{argmin}_z \|(\displaystyle\frac{Czz^TC}{z^TCz}-C)b\|^2$

where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the Euclidean norm. A few observations:

1. The right hand side $C$ term may be factored out.
2. $z^TCz=\|Cz\|^2$ since $\|Cz\|^2=(Cz)^T(Cz)=z^TC^TCz=z^TCCz=z^TCz$ using the fact that $C$ is symmetric and idempotent.
3. The $(i,j)$ entry of $zz^T$ is $z_iz_j$ and is symmetric.
4. $z_i^k=z_i$ since $z_i\in\{0,1\}$

Comment: After factoring $C$ out, you’ve basically got $C$ times the orthogonal rejection of $b$ from $z$, but using an inner product defined by $C$ instead of the usual Euclidean product.

Comment: Thank you for your observation. Do you have any insight on whether this might help move forward with the problem?